# Format change after a certain sign with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, string, wordpress

i'm new here.

I'm using wordpress with the jquery library.

Wordpress generates with `<?php the_title() ?>` a string in a div tag for each article. P.e:

```
<div class="title">Building XY | Switzerland</div>
```

This generates **Building XY  | Switzerland** with the css formating:

My question is, how to change the formating of the part after "Building XY" (from | till end of the string).

I would like to have this:
**Building XY**  | Switzerland

I'm sure the solution is a really simple script. But I'm not well-versed. Or it's may be easier with php?

Thank you for your support :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to wrap the last part in an element to apply styles to it, and then set the appropriate styles, probably `font-weight : normal`

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.title').html(function (_, html) {
        return html.split('|').join('| <span style="font-weight:normal">') + '</span>';
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jSHtU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could also work:
Matches alphanumerics from the end of the string up to the |. Then returns the match with span wrapped around it. The class "yournewclass" would be the class you want to apply to the matched text.

```
jQuery('.title').html().replace(/(\|\s?\w+)$/, function(_,$1){
   return '<span class="yournewclass">' + $1 + '</span>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@adeneo's answer is quite simple and will work in 90percents case.

But what happens if you don t have a | separator in your title ?

i would suggest using a excellent Wordpress extension called "Advanced Custom Field".

This extension can hugely enhance your post edition with new field like a subtitle or a second title ( for example the country part of your title ) or whatever you want !

this way you will just have to wrote your html, natively, without JS like this :

> ```
>  <div id=`title`><? the_title()?></div><<div id=`secondtitle`><? get_field(`scdtitle`); ?></div>
> ```

Comment: `But what happens if you don t have a | separator in your title ?` The OP clearly mentioned

Comment: That would also be a useful solution. Thank you. :-)

Comment: to ling.s : if the | is mandatory then you should perharps insert it into one of the variable , or eventually in a third managed by a checkbox inside WP admin :)